# Mocking Spring Security classes

Tags: java, mockito

I tried to create tests for my method in UserServiceImpl class:

```
@Override
    public User getActualUser() throws WebSecurityException {
        Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
        if (!(authentication instanceof AnonymousAuthenticationToken)) {
            return userRepository.findByLogin(authentication.getName());
        }
        throw new WebSecurityException("Authenticated user not found");
    }
```

but I always get NullPointerException even if my authentication is instance of AnonymousAuthenticationToken, tests always goes to `return userRepository.findByLogin(authentication.getName());` line.

This is my test class:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class UserServiceImplTest {

    @InjectMocks
    UserServiceImpl userService;

    @Mock
    UserRepository userRepository;

@Test(expected = WebSecurityException.class)
    public void testGetActualUserWhenAuthenticationIsInstanceOfAnonymousAuthenticationToken() {

        //SETUP
        SecurityContext securityContext = mock(SecurityContext.class);
        Authentication authentication = mock(AnonymousAuthenticationToken.class);
        when(securityContext.getAuthentication()).thenReturn(authentication);

        //CALL
        userService.getActualUser();
    }

    @Test
    public void testGetActualUserWhenAuthenticationIsNotInstanceOfAnonymousAuthenticationToken() {

        //SETUP
        User user = new User();
        Authentication authentication = mock(Authentication.class);
        when(userRepository.findByLogin(anyString())).thenReturn(user);
        when(authentication.getName()).thenReturn("user");

        //CALL
        userService.getActualUser();

        //TODO VERIFY
    }

}
```

Could you create proper tests for this method?

Comment: Why are you writing this `getActualUser` method instead of just using `@AuthenticationPrincipal`?

Comment: I'm at the beginning of my journey with Spring Security, and this is my first configuration of Spring Security with a database, but I don't use `@AuthenticationPrincipal` because it returns `UserDetails` and I need my custom `User` entity with more custom fields from a database.

Comment: `@AuthenticationPrincipal` doesn't return a `UserDetails` specifically--it will provide whatever the actual principal object is. If yours is `CustomUser`, then you can say `@AuthenticationPrincipal CustomUser user`.

Comment: I read docs carefully and now I understand. Thanks for the advice. I will change my code to use @AuthenticationPrincipal instead of this method. BTW. Is it really wrong practice to use method like this instead of using above annotation?

Comment: It is a bad practice to write code to do something that is already available for you, because it's more work and provides opportunities for bugs. The whole idea behind Spring is that common utility functions like mapping HTTP requests and keeping track of security attributes are provided for you, so you can focus on your business code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to:

```
SecurityContextHolder.setContext(/*mock*/securityContext);
```

... in your test setup, this will fix the primary `NullPointerException`!